# "unresolved import thiserror" when expanding the code with "rustc -Zunpretty=expanded"

Tags: rust

My `Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "rust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
thiserror = { version = "1.0.30", default-features = false }
```

My `rustc --version`

```
rustc 1.59.0-nightly (cfa3fe5af 2021-12-31)
```

My package structure

```
src/
  error.rs
  lib.rs
  main.rs
```

My `lib.rs`

```
pub mod error;
```

My `error.rs`

```
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum DataStoreError {
    #[error("the data for key `{0}` is not available")]
    Redaction(String),
    #[error("invalid header (expected {expected:?}, found {found:?})")]
    InvalidHeader { expected: String, found: String },
    #[error("unknown data store error")]
    Unknown,
}
```

I am trying to expand the `error.rs` to understand what `#[derive(Error, Debug)]` does to the code. However, running

`rustc -Zunpretty=expanded src/error.rs`

results in 5 errors, the first of which is `unresolved import thiserror`, which makes me think I need to change how I invoke the compiler, perhaps with a full module path to error?

Comment: You probably want to use `cargo expand` instead of running `rustc` manually.

Comment: what is the correct usage of that command in this case, simply using `cargo expand src/error.rs` gives me: `error: Invalid value for '<ITEM>': Invalid path segment: "error.rs" is not an identifier`

Answer (score 2):

rustc does not know about the crates in Cargo.toml. It does not know about this file at all. It's Cargo that uses it, and passes things as flags to rustc.

Don't do this work manually. It'll require replicating all of the work Cargo does.

Instead, Cargo has a command for running rustc commands: `cargo rustc`. You pass the arguments to rustc after the `--`:

```sh
cargo rustc -- -Zunpretty=expanded
```

However, there is not a flag to filter the results. Passing a filename to rustc just causes it to consider this file as the entry point, and it will not work with Cargo since it passes its own file as the entry point: `lib.rs` or `main.rs`.

However, as stated in the comment from @Cerberus, it's preferred to use `cargo expand`. Note that it does not take a filename but a path, so to expand `error` it will look like:

```sh
cargo expand error
```

And to expand `DataStoreError`:

```sh
cargo expand error::DataStoreError
```